# Is there a way to mute audio of a video played by vlc by default for every video?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I want to to pre-mute the file right at the start so as to avoid having to do it manually.
I am using windows 10

Comment: idk for Windows, but in the audio prefs on the Mac version there's an option to "keep audio level between sessions" - so you turn it down once & then can forget it. the alternative is 'always reset audio start level to…' which you could set to zero.

Comment: I found similar in Win… will add an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VLC Prefs [under the Tools menu], audio section…

Audio Settings > check 'Always reset audio start level to:' then set the slider to zero

[image]

I suppose you *could* simply disable audio, but that way you'd have to jump into prefs to re-enable it, whereas setting initial volume to zero would allow you the usual 'mouse scroll' to turn it up.